# Trying to pass a structure in c over a FIFO

Tags: c, struct, fifo

I'm trying to pass a structure over a FIFO in c but cant seem to get the structure over to the client. Any help would be appreciated.

created the structure and wrote it to the pipe. Not sure if i did it correctly. Opened the FIFO in the client and cant get anything to print out on that side.
*update*

Here is my updated code and what I'm trying to do. I added a switch statement to the helper function and added a case to triple the number as well.

how would i go about making the program looping until i decided to finally exit and terminate it? would i just put the whole `if(mkfifo("ClientFifo", 0777) == -1)` statment in a while loop and exit or terminate in the switch statement with a new case, or how would I go upon doing that.

I've seen other examples of server client programs, but they all seem to just continue looping and dont exit or terminate.

Thanks again

Server.c with switch statment

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>

struct Client {
    int clientNum;
    int systemCall;
    int num;
    int result;
}client;

struct Client get_student_data()
{
    struct Client s;
    s.clientNum = getpid();
    printf("Client Number:%d", s.clientNum);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Enter System Call number:");
    scanf("%d", &s.systemCall);
    printf("Enter Number:");
    scanf("%d", &s.num);
    printf("system call:%d\n", s.systemCall);

    switch (s.systemCall)
    {
    case 1:
        printf("Youre in case 1\n");
        s.result = s.num * s.num; 
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("Youre in case 2\n");
        s.result = s.num * s.num * s.num;
        break;
    default:
        printf("INVALID CHOICE\n");
        s.result = 0;
        break;
    }
    
    return s;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {//main
   
   //makes fifo  
   if(mkfifo("ClientFifo", 0777) == -1)
   {
        //error message in case fifo isnt created
        if(errno != EEXIST){
        printf("Could not create fifo file\n");
        return 1;
        }//end error checking
 
    //area to do work
    printf("\n");
    struct Client c1 = get_student_data();
    printf("\nClient number: %d\n",c1.clientNum);
    printf("System call number: %d\n",c1.systemCall);
    printf("Paramet number: %d\n",c1.num);
    printf("Result number: %d\n",c1.result);
    
    
    //opens and closes FIFO
    printf("Opening...\n");
    int fd = open("ClientFifo", O_WRONLY);
    printf("Opened\n");

    if(write(fd, &c1, sizeof(c1)) == -1){
    return 2;
    }
    //}//ends write
    //Closes fd
    printf("Written..\n");
    close(fd);
    
    return 0;
}//ends if fifo   
    
}//ends main
```

Client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>

struct Client {
    int clientNum;
    int systemCall;
    int num;
    int result;
}client;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

   if(mkfifo("ClientFifo", 0777)== -1)
   {
    if(errno != EEXIST){
    printf("Could not create fifo file\n");
    return 1;
    }
    printf("Opened\n");
    int fd = open("ClientFifo", O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1) {
        return 1;
    }
    
         printf("Reading\n");
          read(fd, &client, sizeof(client)); 
          printf("Client number:  %d\n", client.clientNum);
          printf("System call number:  %d\n", client.systemCall);
          printf("Parameter number %d\n", client.num);
          printf("Result %d\n", client.result);
      
    close(fd);
    
    return 0;

}//end if   
    
}//end main
```

Comment: `if(mkfifo("ClientFifo", 0777))` According to the doco, if successful this function returns `0`. Your conditional only enters the body of the `if()` when `mkfifo()` has FAILED... You need to think about what you are implementing...

Comment: ok i think i fixed that, is this what you meant `code`(mkfifo("ClientFifo", 0777) == -1)`code`I actually get into the body of my code now. I just don't think that I'm writing anything to the FIFO

Comment: sorry im new to posting on stack flow so bare with me

Comment: Go for a walk and think about the problem... What to do if `mkfifo()` fails; what to do if it succeeds (and returns `0`)... It's okay to evaluate a condition, and if it fails, then print an error message and exit immediately. Don't get into _nesting_ conditions deeply so that the processing all happens way off to the right of the screen, and error handling is way down at the bottom. Move those confirmation `printf()`'s from the `main()` up to the helper function `get_student_data()`... Keep it clean and crisp and clear!!!

Comment: Thanks I finally got it working and receiving the given data!

Comment: Good to hear... If you keep your code clean & neat, you'll soon start to spot problems simply because _that doesn't look right_... Experience can't be bought... And, read the man pages for functions you use, and even those that sound interesting. You can learn a lot... Cheers... To make this question worth storing, maybe post your own answer (with working code) below, explaining what you did to remedy the problem.

Comment: `sizeof(int) * 5` is not correct. Do the same on the sender as the receiver., `sizeof client`

Comment: `sizeof(int) * 5` was from a previous version where i was trying to send just an array of numbers. It was commented out `//sizeof(int) * 5`

Comment: how would i go about making the program looping until i decided to finally exit and terminate it? would i just put the whole `if(mkfifo("ClientFifo", 0777) == -1)` statment in a while loop and exit or terminate in the switch statement with a new case, or how would I go upon doing that. I've seen other examples of server client programs, but they all seem to just continue looping and dont exit or terminate

Answer (score 0):

Here follows an example of a way of passing data between a client and a server program using a `FIFO` connector.

The example here is asynchronous --- *non-blocking* --- and it can be helpful to see the difference from your code to this one. I will not say it is good or better or even correct. But it was cut from another program that has been working here.

> how would i go about making the program looping until i decided to finally exit and terminate it? would i just put the whole if(mkfifo("ClientFifo", 0777) == -1) statment in a while loop and exit or terminate in the switch statement with a new case, or how would I go upon doing that.

Well, the pipe thing on disk is just a reference and can be there well before you start your programs around it. And will stay there. It will make no difference on how you start or end your `FIFO`. There is no single program around a `FIFO` unless you put the same program on the 2 sides of the pipe: there are always two connections.

When one side of `FIFO` terminates the other side should also end, since a pipe is a connector only and --- as a network connection --- it is alive only while a connection exists.

### about the example

Code will be in a header file, a lib file, server and client code.

#### the data

```
typedef struct
{
    char id[16];
    char name[16];
    char creation_log[64];
    char payload[928 + 9 * 1024];

} Packet;  // 10K area
```

This is the packet used, an useless `10K` area. A simple helper *factory function*  creates numbered record for use, `get_data()`. Another helper `show_data()` displays the data and is used on client and server. This is an example of the output:

```
Packet = {
    id: "1000",
    name: "process 004389",
    23/10/10 01:30:16 process 004389 id is 1000
}
```

`payload` is ignored. `id` is numbered from `1000` on. `name` gets the `pid` of the server program, and `creation_log` is a timestamp, as shown. It is the equivalent of your `Client`

So the header `stuff.h` is

#### `stuff.h`

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct
{
    char id[16];
    char name[16];
    char creation_log[64];
    char payload[928 + 9 * 1024];

} Packet;  // 10K area

int     check_fifo(const char*);
Packet* get_data(const char* payload);
int     show_data(Packet* pack);
```

`check_fifo()` gets a name and returns 0 if such named `FIFO` is available. It is created if not in disk. The default name is *`test_pipe`* but it can be entered on the command line, as usual in `C`.

#### `O_NONBLOCK` in the server side of the `FIFO`

The `open` call returns immediately if a reader is already connected, or returns `-1` and `ENXIO` if there is no one there.
Just as an example, `fnctl()` is called to get and set the `FIFO` size:

Then this `monitor` `struct` is passed to `poll` and as expected with a name like this, monitor the existence of the reader at the other side of the pipe or a timeout. This is all there is.

```
    struct pollfd monitor = {
        .fd = out, .events = POLLERR, .revents = 0};
```

This is the call:

```
    int ch = poll(&monitor, 1, 5000);
```

This is one way the server ends: when the reader closes, the server gets `POLLERR`. Other way is by signal, via `SIGINT`, by pressing Control-C or sending the signal to the process. The `pid` is in the logs to the client so it can even be sent from there using `kill`. `5000` is a 5s timeout.

#### code for `server.c`

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include "stuff.h"

void game_over(int S);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int                out          = -1;
    size_t             res          = 0;
    const unsigned int interval     = 2;
    const char*        default_name = "test_pipe";
    char               f_name[150]  = {0};

    signal(SIGINT, game_over);
    if (argc > 1)
        strcpy(f_name, argv[1]);
    else
        strcpy(f_name, default_name);

    res = check_fifo(f_name);
    if (res != 0) return -1;

    while (1)
    {
        out = open(f_name, O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
        if (out < 0)
        {
            if (errno == ENXIO)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "    ENXIO: No readers for \"%s\"\n", f_name);
                fprintf(stderr, "    Waiting...\n");
                sleep(interval);
                continue;
            }
            fprintf(
                stderr, "    Error opening \"%s\": %s\n", f_name,
                strerror(errno));
            return -3;
        };
        fprintf(stderr, "    \"%s\" is open for writing\n", f_name);
        break;
    }
    // now a server is online and there is at least one
    // reader
    res = fcntl(out, F_GETPIPE_SZ);
    fprintf(stderr, "    original FIFO size is = %lu\n", res);
    // now change size to 10 Packets
    res = fcntl(out, F_SETPIPE_SZ, sizeof(Packet));
    if (res == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "    Error setting size of FIFO\n");
        close(out);
        return -3;
    }
    res = fcntl(out, F_GETPIPE_SZ);
    fprintf(
        stderr,
        "\
        FIFO size is now %lu\n\
        size of packet is %lu\n",
        res, sizeof(Packet));

    struct pollfd monitor = {.fd = out, .events = POLLERR, .revents = 0};
    while (1)
    {
        Packet* pack = get_data(NULL);
        res          = write(out, pack, sizeof(Packet));
        if (res == sizeof(Packet))
        {
            show_data(pack);
            free(pack);
        }
        else
        {
            free(pack);
            fprintf(stderr, "\t%lu bytes recorded at FIFO\n", res);
            if (res < 0)
            {
                fprintf(
                    stderr, "    Error writing to \"%s\": %s\n", f_name,
                    strerror(errno));
            }
            break;
        }
        // wait for the reader to consume the data
        int ch = poll(&monitor, 1, 5000);
        if (ch == 0) continue;  // timeout
        // readers are gone
        fprintf(stderr, "    reader is gone. Aborting\n");
        break;
    }
    close(out);
    return 0;
}  // main

void game_over(int S)
{
    fprintf(
        stderr,
        "\n\tSIGINT received: program interrupted. "
        "Aborting.\n");
    exit(-3);
}
```

This is just a toy. We should not call `fprintf()` inside a signal handler.

#### The client side: `client.c`

This is even simpler:

Since the `open` always succeeds, the client just uses `poll()` and wait. If `poll()` gets `POLLIN` there is something to read. If it gets `POLLHUP` then the server died. A timeout can occur while waiting for the server to go online.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include "stuff.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const char*        default_name = "test_pipe";
    char               f_name[150]  = {0};
    if (argc > 1)
        strcpy(f_name, argv[1]);
    else
        strcpy(f_name, default_name);

    int res = check_fifo(f_name);
    if (res != 0) return -1;

    int in = open(f_name, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
    if (in < 0)
    {
        fprintf(
            stderr, "    Error opening \"%s\": %s\n", f_name, strerror(errno));
        return -3;
    };
    fprintf(stderr, "    \"%s\" is open for reading\n", f_name);

    struct pollfd monitor = {.fd = in, .events = POLLIN, .revents = 0};
    Packet        pack    = {0};
    while (1)
    {
        int ch = poll(&monitor, 1, 8 * 1000);
        if (ch == 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "    timeout: no data from server...\n");
            break;  // timeout
        }

        if (monitor.revents & POLLIN)
        {  // normal
            res = read(in, &pack, sizeof(pack));
            if (res == sizeof(Packet))
            {
                show_data(&pack);
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "    fragmented: %d bytes read\n", res);
                break;
            }
        }

        if (monitor.revents & POLLHUP)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "\tPOLLHUP: the server is gone\n");
            break;
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "\trevents: %d\n", monitor.revents);
        break;

    };  // while()
    close(in);
    return 0;
}  // main
```

#### `stuff.c`: the helper functions

```
#include "stuff.h"

#include <stdio.h>

int check_fifo(const char* f_name)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "    FIFO is \"%s\"\n", f_name);
    int res = mkfifo(f_name, 0777);
    if (res == 0) return 0;
    if (errno == EEXIST)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "    \"%s\": already exists\n", f_name);
        return 0;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "    Error opening \"%s\": %s\n", f_name, strerror(errno));
    return -1;
}

Packet* get_data(const char* payload)
{
    static int   usn  = 999;
    unsigned int pid  = getpid();
    Packet*      pack = malloc(sizeof(Packet));
    if (pack == NULL) return NULL;
    // id counts up from usn
    sprintf(pack->id, "%d", ++usn);
    // name is "Process nnNNnn"
    sprintf(pack->name, "process %06d", pid);
    // creation_log is
    //"yy:mm:dd hh:mm:ss from server running as process
    // 123456"
    char       timestr[20];
    time_t     tm;
    struct tm* temp;
    tm   = time(NULL);
    temp = localtime(&tm);
    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        free(pack);
        return (NULL);
    }
    int res = strftime(timestr, sizeof(timestr), "%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S", temp);
    if (res == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "strftime returned 0");
        free(pack);
        return NULL;
    }
    sprintf(
        pack->creation_log, "%s %s id is %s", timestr, pack->name, pack->id);
    return pack;
};

int show_data(Packet* pack)
{
    if (pack == NULL) return -1;
    fprintf(
        stderr,
        "\
        Packet = {\n\
            id: \"%s\",\n\
            name: \"%s\",\n\
            %s\n\
        }\n\n",
        pack->id, pack->name, pack->creation_log);
    return 0;
};
```

#### output

Server starting on terminal, with no reader, cancelled by control-C

```
[SO@Fedora38 fifo]$ ./server new_pipe
    FIFO is "new_pipe"
    "new_pipe": already exists
    ENXIO: No readers for "new_pipe"
    Waiting...
    ENXIO: No readers for "new_pipe"
    Waiting...
^C
        SIGINT received: program interrupted. Aborting.
```

Client started with no Server

```
[SO@Fedora38 fifo]$ ./client new_pipe
    FIFO is "new_pipe"
    "new_pipe": already exists
    "new_pipe" is open for reading
```

Server started with reader online, starts sending data

```
[SO@Fedora38 fifo]$ ./server new_pipe
    FIFO is "new_pipe"
    "new_pipe": already exists
    "new_pipe" is open for writing
    original FIFO size is = 65536
        FIFO size is now 16384
        size of packet is 10240
        Packet = {
            id: "1000",
            name: "process 005903",
            23/10/10 02:43:19 process 005903 id is 1000
        }
```

and the corresponding output on the client side:

```
[SO@Fedora38 fifo]$ ./client new_pipe
    FIFO is "new_pipe"
    "new_pipe": already exists
    "new_pipe" is open for reading
        Packet = {
            id: "1000",
            name: "process 006074",
            23/10/10 02:45:46 process 006074 id is 1000
        }

        Packet = {
            id: "1001",
            name: "process 006074",
            23/10/10 02:45:51 process 006074 id is 1001
        }

        POLLHUP: the server is gone
```

When the server ends `poll()` at the client side gets `POLLHUP`.

When the client ends `poll()` at the server side gets `POLLERR` and the server ends too.

```
[SO@Fedora38 fifo]$ ./server new_pipe
    FIFO is "new_pipe"
    "new_pipe": already exists
    "new_pipe" is open for writing
    original FIFO size is = 65536
        FIFO size is now 16384
        size of packet is 10240
        Packet = {
            id: "1000",
            name: "process 006343",
            23/10/10 02:48:34 process 006343 id is 1000
        }

    reader is gone. Aborting
```